# SELECT clause with condition

Tags: sql, oracle

Help me explain what is this question meant.

"Find all combination of employee names and department names."

For my table

```
//EMPLOYEE 
E#       ENAME       DNAME
-----------------------------
1         JOHN         IT
2         MAY         SCIENCE
3         SITI        SCIENCE

//DEPARTMENT
DNAME
------------
RESEARCH
   IT
 SCIENCE
```

just for my understanding. what is the question want me to do?
i used the following query

```
SELECT ENAME,DNAME FROM EMPLOYEE;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bit unclear, but to find all combinations you would create a [Cartesian product.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)

```
select
  e.ename, d.dname
from
  employee e,
  dname d
```

Oracle supports the above sql and uses [`CROSS JOIN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.2.2/ref/rrefsqljcrossjoin.html) as well to mean the same thing.

```
select
  e.ename, d.dname
from
  employee e cross join dname d
```

This joins each row in the `employee` table to each other row in the `dname` table.

This would create:

```
ENAME       DNAME
---------------------
JOHN         IT
JOHN         SCIENCE
JOHN         RESEARCH
MAY         SCIENCE
MAY         RESEARCH
MAY         IT
SITI        SCIENCE
SITI        IT
SITI        RESEARCH
```

Comment: actually i just want to know the question meaning and i didn't expect you post the code here. if i know the explanation like this i should able to code it . anyway thanks you

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is they want you to create a cartesian:

```
select 
    EMPLOYEE.ENAME
    ,DEPARTMENT.DNAME
FROM EMPLOYEE, DEPARTMENT
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
select employee.ENAME,department.DNAME from employee,department
```